# agrep working with del, ins arguments

Tags: r, arguments, string-matching, agrep

How can "abteam" with "ab" be matched using this code?

```
agrep("abteam",c("acb","abd","ab"),value=T,ignore.case = TRUE,max = list(del = 10, ins = 10, sub = 10))
```

The result is `character(0)`, though I specified `del=10`, `ins=10`. What is the problem? How does `agrep` work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the help file:

> If ‘cost’ is not given, ‘all’ defaults to 10%, and the other transformation number bounds default to ‘all’.

As far as I understand it means that either `cost` or `all` is a limiting factor even if you set `del`, `ins` and `sub`. If you want to allow 10 transformations you can simply set `max = 10`. Additional parameters can be used to limit specific transformations, for example:

```
> x <- c("fooar","ooar","foobaz")
> agrep("foobar", x, value=T, max = list(all = 3, del = 0, ins = 0))
[1] "foobaz"
```

In your case you could use `max = list(all = 10 ,del = 10, ins = 10, sub = 10))`.

Comment: Thanks! It works. Is it possible to give importance to particular part of the string? Say, matching should be done based on first name rather than second name.

Comment: As far as I am concerned no. If you want something like you'll have to provide your own logic.

Comment: To be honest, this still doesn't make sense to me. For the OP's example, if one uses `agrep(pat, x, value=T, max = list(all = 10 ,del = 10, ins = 0, sub = 10))` nothing is returned. That makes no sense - 4 deletions, nothing else, and `"abteam"` matches `"ab"`.

Comment: Good point. What is interesting [Python TRE library](https://github.com/laurikari/tre/) returns a match: `import tre; fz=tre.Fuzzyness(maxerr=10, maxdel=10, maxins=0, maxsub=10);  pt=tre.compile("abteam"); pt.search("ab", fz)`.

Comment: @zero323 - well, I'm stumped then. `agrep` is so utterly confusing to me that I have usually used `adist` in the past instead - at least it gives nice clear values I can test against.

Comment: @thelatemail Separation of insertions and deletions suggests it is actually asymmetric, but it is not supported by Python behavior. There is definitely something weird going on here. `adist` is pretty nice. Another alternative is [Biostrings](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/Biostrings.html) library.